# Найти одинаковые элементы (объекты) 2-х массивов

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть 2 массива разной длины, у которых элементы являются объектами. 
Хотелось бы получить результат в виде массива, с этими элементами. Вот 2 массива:

```
var arr1 = [{timeFormat: "00:00", timestamp: 1443128400000}, {timeFormat: "00:15", timestamp: 1443129300000}, {timeFormat: "02:15", timestamp: 1443136500000}];
    var arr2 = [{timeFormat: "00:00", timestamp: 1443128400000}, {timeFormat: "01:00", timestamp: 1443132000000}, {timeFormat: "02:15", timestamp: 1443136500000}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yq0or6ct/4/ тут я пыталась сравнивать по индексу, на обычный массив все находит, а вот когда объекты в виде элементов - нет. Подскажите как правильно нужно сделать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Intersec(arr1, arr2) {
    var idx = 0, arr3 = [];
    var tmp = []; // временный массив JSON

    for(var i in arr1){ // переводим в JSON
        tmp.push(JSON.stringify(arr1[i]));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        idx = tmp.indexOf(JSON.stringify(arr2[i])); // сравниваем в формате JSON
        if (idx >= 0) arr3.push(arr2[i]);
    }

    return arr3;
}

var arr1 = [{timeFormat: "00:00", timestamp: 1443128400000}, {timeFormat: "00:15", timestamp: 1443129300000}, {timeFormat: "02:15", timestamp: 1443136500000}];
var arr2 = [{timeFormat: "00:00", timestamp: 1443128400000}, {timeFormat: "01:00", timestamp: 1443132000000}, {timeFormat: "02:15", timestamp: 1443136500000}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(Intersec(arr1, arr2)));
```

Идея: чтобы `.indexOf()` работал, надо чтобы значения были простые - строки, числа. Cравниваем элементы массива на основе строкового представления JSON.

Comment: Если местами поменять порядок ключей, то работать перестанет.