# Как правильно склеить массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, arraylist

Есть массив вида:

```
var data = [
    {"time":["00:00"],"workstation":4,"worker":4},
    {"time":["00:00","01:45","03:30","05:15","07:00","08:45","10:30","12:15","14:00"],"workstation":11,"worker":4},
    {"time":["02:40"],"workstation":14,"worker":1},
    {"time":["02:40"],"workstation":4,"worker":1},
    {"time":["17:30","19:15","21:00","22:45"],"workstation":4,"worker":1},
    {"time":["17:30","19:15","21:00","22:45"],"workstation":14,"worker":1}
];
```

(Время хранится в timestamp.Для упрощения сделала пока в нормальном формате. Здесь исходный массив http://jsfiddle.net/p2exsn36/1/ )

То есть каждый элемент - это объект вида:

```
 {
     "time" : [],
     "workstation" : 14,
     "worker" : 1       
 }
```

В этом объекте в массиве time есть дубли времени, также worker может быть разный и workstation.
На выходе хотелось бы получить "чистый" массив вида :

```
[
    {"time" : "00:00", "workstation" : [14,5], "worker" : [1,4]}, 
    {"time" : "01:45", "workstation" : [11], "worker" : [4]}
]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно их можно склеить? Спасибо! Только только начинаю осваивать javascript

Comment: И какой же момент вызывает затруднения? Вы хоть что-то пробовали сами сделать?

Comment: Если честно не вижу существенных отличий с этими Вашими вопросами:
[раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455008/), [два](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453541/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, только надо на ES5 переписать:

```js
var data = [
    {"time":["00:00"],"workstation":4,"worker":4},
    {"time":["00:00","01:45","03:30","05:15","07:00","08:45","10:30","12:15","14:00"],"workstation":11,"worker":4},
    {"time":["02:40"],"workstation":14,"worker":1},
    {"time":["02:40"],"workstation":4,"worker":1},
    {"time":["17:30","19:15","21:00","22:45"],"workstation":4,"worker":1},
    {"time":["17:30","19:15","21:00","22:45"],"workstation":14,"worker":1}
];

var res = Object.create(null), item, time, cur;

for (item of data) {
  for (time of item.time) {
    cur = res[time] = res[time] || { time:time, workstation:[], worker:[] };
    ~cur.workstation.indexOf(item.workstation) || cur.workstation.push(item.workstation);
    ~cur.worker.indexOf(item.worker) || cur.worker.push(item.worker);
  }
}

res = Object.keys(res).map(function(key) { return res[key] });

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, "  "));
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/marcuzy/p2exsn36/2/ вот как-то так. спасибо

Comment: @ennet, не надо ходить по массивам при помощи for-in - это неэффективно и потенциально опасно. Используй нормальный цикл до длины массива. Дальше, зачем по ключу присваивать сам ключ в качестве значения я не понимаю. Ну и наконец, то, что у тебя там получается не соответствует тому, что ты просила в вопросе.